# How to style links generated by the get_category_parents wordpress's function?

Tags: wordpress

I am using a code to generate categories hierarchy using `get_category_parents()` in wordpress. and it works fine, but i want to change the link's color by filtering this function by adding an inline style to the anchor link.

So How to do that? Or just can't filter any function while this function does not contain a hook , and i mean by this the `apply_filter()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on the developer documentation : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_parents/#source

There is actually no filter on the output. So the only way, the best one though, is to use CSS for this matter :

```
// We fetch them : 
$cats = get_category_parents($category_id);
if(!is_wp_error($cats)) : 
   // Let's wrap everything :
   echo '<div class="parent-categories">'; 
   echo $cats
   echo '</div>';
endif;
```

And then in your css :

```
.parent-categories a:first-child{color: red;}
.parent-categories a:last-child{color: blue;}
.parent-categories a:nth-child(2){color: pink;}
// and so on
```

See : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot. it helped